# What is the specific security implication with the permission "Select method for cancelling account"

Tags: users, security

Below the permission "Select method for cancelling account" there is the following hint:

> Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

I understand that it is dangerous to give this permission to users who have created content, because they might for example unpublish their content.

However, I want to give the permission to users who have no possibility to create any content, and I wonder if there is any other security implication that hasn't yet come to my mind.

Comment: Security as in it's not secure for the whole integrity of your site if someone without the proper knowledge accidentally deletes a whole bunch of content (public and private) together with a deleted account.

Comment: Can these users delete _other_ user accounts or just their own?